# Why did my site votes (stars) disappeared from Google SERP?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, rich-snippets

I figured out that my website stars disappeared suddenly. What should I do to get my website votes (stars) back?

My website stars had been removed since 1 month ago.

My website is WordPress and I am using kkstar plugin.

[image]

Comment: See also: [Aggregate Rating not displayed in Google search results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91492/aggregate-rating-not-displayed-in-google-search-results)

Comment: Seem to be working now, did you change anything?  : https://www.google.co.th/search?q=%22https%3A%2F%2Fkhedmatazma.com%2Fcarry-cargo%2F%22&oq=%22https%3A%2F%2Fkhedmatazma.com%2Fcarry-cargo%2F%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.1863j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

From the Structured Data Testing Tool. You can see that there is no review markup present on your website.

This link is specific to your website -
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=khedmatazma.com

You need to change the plugin that you are using or change the config to render the markup correctly.

This is an example of how it would look like if implemented correctly.
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review. Click on embed markup in the example.

Comment: you cheked homepage we dont have stars on it. please check " https://khedmatazma.com/carry-cargo/ " this page has voting in serp and suddenly disappeard and gone.

Comment: That URL redirects to https://khedmatazma.com/subservice/moving, which does not have any Review structured data either.

Answer (score 1):

Google is taking away review stars in the SERPs for structured data that is on the website, if the reviews are about that website. Google now considers this "self-serving" structured data markup.